# Retrain Mobilenet_SSD KeyError: 'eval_input_fns'

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, I am trying to retrain the Mobilenet_SSD_V2 object detection with tensorflow. I am having difficulty when running the object_detection/model_mail.py script as it is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 110, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 74, in main
    eval_input_fns = train_and_eval_dict['eval_input_fns']
KeyError: 'eval_input_fns'
```

I have been following the [Running Locally](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md) page from tensorflow to try and train the network, but I've been having no luck.

Here's the train_config portion of my pipeline.config file:

```
train_config {
  batch_size: 24
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.00400000018999
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.949999988079
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.899999976158
      decay: 0.899999976158
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/owl/jetson_nano_detection_and_tracking/data/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  num_steps: 50000
  load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/data/pet_label_detection.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/data/pet_faces_train.record-?????-of-00010"
  }
}
eval_config {
  num_examples: 8000
  max_evals: 10
  use_moving_averages: false
  retain_original_images: true
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/data/pet_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/data/pet_faces_val.record-?????-of-00010"
  }
}
```